# how to check if a video id exists on youtube

Tags: php, youtube, google-api

what am trying to do is check if the video entered by the users really exists or not , I have searched a lot and found this : [ReRetrieving_Video_Entry](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php?csw=1#Retrieving_Video_Entry) , but it looks like it deprecated, so how is it possible using `Google APIs Client Library for PHP` to check if video exists or not?

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: Did you read the deprecation notice on that page link from your question? *"**Note:** The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well."* - Use the newer version https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/ - There's your "answer" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed it using this technique, which doesn't require any use of `API`:

```
   $headers = get_headers('https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $key);

    if(is_array($headers) ? preg_match('/^HTTP\\/\\d+\\.\\d+\\s+2\\d\\d\\s+.*$/',$headers[0]) : false){
        // video exists

    } else {
        // video does not exist
        echo json_encode(array('Error','There is no video with that Id!'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Here's what I'm using, it works pretty well. [Youtube API v2. Deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries)</strike>

```
$video = "cK3N2DC3Fds";            
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$video);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($content && $content !== "Invalid id" && $content !== "No longer available") {           
    $xml   = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
}else {
 //Doesn't exist
}
```

You can check if a video exists using [YouTube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search_by_keyword). Download/clone the API from [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

And here's a script I made that check if a video exists given a youtube video ID.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../google-api/src/Google/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located

    $DEVELOPER_KEY = 'yourkey';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);

  // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    $video = "cK3N2DC3Fds"; //Youtube video ID
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id', array(
      'q' => $video, //The search query, can be a name or anything,
      'maxResults' => 1, //Query result limit
      "type" => "video"
    ));

    $exists = false;
    foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
        //if type is video, this will always be "youtuve#video"
        if($searchResult['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video"){ 
            if($video ==  $searchResult['id']['videoId']){
                $exists = true;
            }
        }
     }

     if(!$exists){
        echo "video not found";
     }else echo "video found";
```

Comment: that feed link always return `No longer available` no matter how many times I changed the video `id`

Comment: Really? Its, actually working in my site, give me a video id, and ill check it out.

Comment: You're right, I'll try tou give you another answer, it's no longer working. sorry.

Comment: @MixedCoder updated my answer with youtube API V3, I run many tests and everything is working!

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I type it fast at work to help the OP,  I will later explain what was done. You're right,  but I wanted to help the OP with his problem right away.